# Search Query and current user in search core web part

Tags: search

Is there a way of making the Fixed Keyword Query in search core web part to get the current user login (Author:{CurrentUser}).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish there was a builtin way to do that, but there is not.  You will need to write a custom Web Part which inherits from CoreResultsWebPart.  You can then use the QueryManager object to change the value of the query.

Comment: Good answer, although there doesn't seem to be a QueryManager object in CoreResultsWebPart. Overwriting the FixedQuery property will do it.

Comment: Update (struggling with it myself): there is a SharedQueryManager.GetInstance property which let's you retrieve a SharedQueryManager object. That one has a QueryManager object to influence the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixed keyword query in core search results web part. Just modify the web part and enter your query in the relevant property.

Comment: That wasn't the question, the question was if he could add something like [Me] or Current User to the fixed field, which can't be done apparantly.